# jQuery animation won't start until second click

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to create a Halloween-themed animation for our website header that involves an image of a spider which moves "randomly" when it's clicked.  I'm really stretching myself on this little project and, while I've managed to get the animation mostly working the way I want, I just can't figure out how to get the animation to start on the first click.  The image doesn't move until the second click, and then it runs pretty much as I intend.

I've read through the answers to several questions about animations that don't start on the first click but none of them have helped me to resolve the problems with my script.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

The animation needs to run on a vendor-controlled platform which is running jQuery 1.7.2.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.  If it wasn't for this site I wouldn't have gotten as far as I have with the script.

HTML:

```
<div id="hd">
    <h1>This is the page title</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum nibh in
nunc euismod, eget elementum est consequat. Aenean tempus augue est. Sed elit
neque, semper a cursus a, semper eu ligula. Nullam tristique augue odio, non
scelerisque massa eleifend nec. Vivamus mollis purus lacus, vel elementum dui
vulputate luctus. Sed rutrum nisl non nisl laoreet, sed consequat massa commodo. 
Maecenas consectetur elementum nulla, sed pellentesque ligula gravida eu.
Suspendisse arcu dui, pretium et fermentum aliquam, eleifend et arcu. Aenean 
placerat porta sapien. Etiam auctor, leo vitae vestibulum mattis, eros risus 
fringilla nibh, id adipiscing turpis ante sed lectus. Quisque turpis metus,
condimentum eget consectetur eu, pulvinar a massa. Maecenas venenatis eros augue, condimentum porttitor erat varius at. Praesent quis semper erat.
</p>
<p>
Duis magna magna, rutrum non massa non, porttitor auctor turpis. Aliquam at 
aliquet dui. Praesent vestibulum lobortis dapibus. Phasellus hendrerit ut nunc 
vitae placerat. Sed sit amet sollicitudin sapien. Morbi imperdiet arcu ipsum, 
nec congue purus dapibus at. Morbi elementum, nibh in viverra imperdiet, felis 
leo eleifend magna, id facilisis mi leo ut mauris.
</p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // add spider image to header
    $('<img id="spider" src="http://lgimages.s3.amazonaws.com/data/imagemanager/41647/spider2.png" alt="Spider hanging from web" />').prependTo('#hd');
    // Note: total height of spider/web image is 620px, so top: -592px positions spider in header area
    $('#spider').css({
        'left' : '125px',
        'top' : '-592px'
    });

    // dropLow: subtract 87% of window height from total height of spider thread image
    // we're trying to get spider to drop to lower area of window, but not below visible area
    var dropLow;
    var dropMax = $(window).height();
    if ( dropMax < 600 ) {
        dropLow = ((dropMax * .87) - 592);
        } else {
        dropLow = "0";
        }

    // generate random number for upper dropdown offset
    function randomFromInterval(lowerRange,upperRange) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(upperRange-lowerRange+1)+lowerRange)* -1;
    }

    // make spider clickable/tappable
    $('#hd').on('click', '#spider', function(){

        $(this).toggle(function() {
            // spider drops down to ready position
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top: dropLow - Math.floor((Math.random() * 80) + 1) + 'px'
            }, 3400);
        }, function() {
            // spider rises
            // randomly generate 1 or -1 as multiplier for a left/right offset
            var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
            $(this).stop().animate({
                // spider rises until partially hidden
                top: '-609px'
            }, 2100, function(){
                $(this).delay(1000).animate({
                    // spider rises until fully hidden
                    top: '-630px'
                }, 1200);

                // calculate a new left offset of spider relative to parent div#hd
                // and add a randomly positive or negative multiplier
                var myNewLeft = $(this).position().left + (plusOrMinus * 36);
                // if new left offset is not outside div#hd, move spider there
                // note that spider is hidden (above window) during this move
                if (myNewLeft > 0 ) {
                    $(this).delay(1000).stop().animate({left: myNewLeft + 'px'});
                }

                $(this).delay(1000).stop().animate({
                    // partially show spider (note top pos change from -630px)
                    top: '-609px'
                }, 1600, function(){
                    $(this).delay(1000).stop().animate({
                        // spider drops a random amount (but stays in header area)
                        top: randomFromInterval(592,495) + 'px'
                    }, 1200);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}); // end ready
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewxhU/) with my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `toggle` handlers are added only when you click the `#spider` for the first time, so the toggle will not get executed on the first click.

```
// make spider clickable/tappable
$('#spider').toggle(function() {
        // spider drops down to ready position
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: dropLow - Math.floor((Math.random() * 80) + 1) + 'px'
        }, 3400);
    }, function() {
        // spider rises
        // randomly generate 1 or -1 as multiplier for a left/right offset
        var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        $(this).stop().animate({
            // spider rises until partially hidden
            top: '-609px'
        }, 2100, function(){
            $(this).delay(1000).animate({
                // spider rises until fully hidden
                top: '-630px'
            }, 1200);

            // calculate a new left offset of spider relative to parent div#hd
            // and add a randomly positive or negative multiplier
            var myNewLeft = $(this).position().left + (plusOrMinus * 36);
            // if new left offset is not outside div#hd, move spider there
            // note that spider is hidden (above window) during this move
            if (myNewLeft > 0 ) {
                $(this).delay(1000).stop().animate({left: myNewLeft + 'px'});
            }

            $(this).delay(1000).stop().animate({
                // partially show spider (note top pos change from -630px)
                top: '-609px'
            }, 1600, function(){
                $(this).delay(1000).stop().animate({
                    // spider drops a random amount (but stays in header area)
                    top: randomFromInterval(592,495) + 'px'
                }, 1200);
            });
        });
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ArgZ2/)

If you want to maintain the current structure for some reason, then you can try to trigger the click function manually after toggle handler is registered [like in here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4yZpF/)

Comment: Thank you Arun for explaining what I did wrong and providing a working demo.  Thanks also for the alternate method of making the script work.  I had tried using `$('#spider').trigger('click');` at the beginning of the script but that didn't work, so I appreciate your showing me how to correctly trigger the click function, too.